# How to select only one plot in a legend of a double plot pie?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have created two plt.pie in the shape of donuts.
The 1st encompassing the 2nd, and the 2nd encompassing the void, a white hole.
I would like to create a plt.legend () but only including the second plot.
I can't seem to select only the second one.

In my caption I want to display each labels of labels_origin with the percentage they represent, as well as the correct color code.

It seems here that he is mixing the colors of my 2 plots.

Anyone have a solution please?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ["Part pertes", "Part humaine", "Part animale", "Part autres utilisations", "Part semences", "Part traitements"]
sizes = [part_pertes , part_humaine , part_animale, part_autres_util, part_semences, part_traitements]

labels_origine = ["Part pertes - Animale", "Part pertes - Végétale",
                  "Part humaine - Animale", "Part humaine - Végétale",
                  "Part animale - Animale", "Part animale - Végétale",
                  "Part autres utilisations - Animale", "Part autres utilisations - Végétale",
                  "Part semences - Animale", "Part semences - Végétale",
                  "Part traitements - Animale", "Part traitements - Végétale"]
sizes_origine = [part_pertes_prod_anim, part_pertes_prod_veget,
                 part_humaine_prod_anim , part_humaine_prod_veget,
                 part_animale_prod_anim, part_animale_prod_veget,
                 part_autres_util_prod_anim,  part_autres_util_prod_veget,
                 part_semences_prod_anim, part_semences_prod_veget,
                 part_traitements_prod_anim,  part_traitements_prod_veget]

size = 0.3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Couleurs
colors = ["#ff5959", "#2693ff", "#59FF59", "#FF8C19", "#3D3DC8", "#ffb3e6"]
colors_origine = ['#ff9999', "#ffd8d8", "#66b3ff", "#a5d2ff", "#99ff99", "#D8FFD8",
                  "#FFAC59", "#FFCB98", "#c2c2f0", "#7B7BDC", "#ffb3e6", "#FFF2FA" ]

#Plot
plot1 = plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=45, pctdistance=0.85,
        textprops={"fontsize":14}, radius=1, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

plot2 = plt.pie(sizes_origine, colors=colors_origine, startangle=45, pctdistance=0.85,
        radius=1-size, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()

total=sum(sizes_origine)

plt.legend(loc=0,
    labels=['%s, %1.1f%%' % (
        l, (float(s) / total) * 100) for l, s in zip(labels_origine, sizes_origine)],
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.7, 1),
    prop={'size': 14},
    title="Origine des parts",
    title_fontsize=16)

plt.title("Répartition des différentes parts de la disponibilité intérieure mondiale", fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[Screenshot of my double plot pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3CYK.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix could be manually setting the legend handles colors. You need to get the current axis with `.gca()`, then get the legend from the axis and manually set the color by iterating over them (the code needs to be inserted after the legend call):

```
ax = plt.gca()
leg = ax.get_legend()
for index, color_origine in enumerate(colors_origine):
    leg.legendHandles[index].set_color(color_origine)
```

Working example with random values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ["Part pertes", "Part humaine", "Part animale", "Part autres utilisations", "Part semences", "Part traitements"]
sizes = [15 , 38 , 200, 10, 25, 44]

labels_origine = ["Part pertes - Animale", "Part pertes - Végétale",
                  "Part humaine - Animale", "Part humaine - Végétale",
                  "Part animale - Animale", "Part animale - Végétale",
                  "Part autres utilisations - Animale", "Part autres utilisations - Végétale",
                  "Part semences - Animale", "Part semences - Végétale",
                  "Part traitements - Animale", "Part traitements - Végétale"]
sizes_origine = [11, 45,
                 100 , 12,
                 24, 3,
                 55,  87,
                 34, 43,
                 22,  77]

size = 0.3
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))


# Couleurs
colors = ["#ff5959", "#2693ff", "#59FF59", "#FF8C19", "#3D3DC8", "#ffb3e6"]
colors_origine = ['#ff9999', "#ffd8d8", "#66b3ff", "#a5d2ff", "#99ff99", "#D8FFD8",
                  "#FFAC59", "#FFCB98", "#c2c2f0", "#7B7BDC", "#ffb3e6", "#FFF2FA" ]

#Plot
plot1 = plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=45, pctdistance=0.85,
        textprops={"fontsize":14}, radius=1, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

plot2 = plt.pie(sizes_origine, colors=colors_origine, startangle=45, pctdistance=0.85,
        radius=1-size, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()

total=sum(sizes_origine)

plt.legend(loc=0,
    labels=['%s, %1.1f%%' % (
        l, (float(s) / total) * 100) for l, s in zip(labels_origine, sizes_origine)],
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.7, 1),
    prop={'size': 14},
    title="Origine des parts",
    title_fontsize=16)

plt.title("Répartition des différentes parts de la disponibilité intérieure mondiale", fontsize=20)

# THIS ↓↓↓↓↓
ax = plt.gca()
leg = ax.get_legend()
for index, color_origine in enumerate(colors_origine):
    leg.legendHandles[index].set_color(color_origine)

plt.show()
```

which outputs:

[image]

Comment: My hero, thank you so much man, it work!